# Sound for a mockumentary genre 

Tags: genre

Anybody have an insight?

Very little fx, little mixing? little ambience?

Answer (score 2):

What style of doc is it mocking?

I'd say that you would want to be very heavy handed. Super-dramatic ambiences and over the top transitions. Gigantic piano/synth hits when something important happens.

Oh, and reverse everything.  Very dramatic.

Comment: lol.  are you serious? have you ever watched a mocumentary?  

Comment: Only half serious...  It's been a while since I last watched a feature length, but if you watch any of the current reality shows (which may as well be mockumentaries) they're covered in stuff like that.

Answer (score 0):

Lots of wind in your microphone.

Comment: hahaha very true